# Как сделать переход по ссылкам в режиме аякс

Tags: jquery, ajax

Как сделать переход по ссылкам в режиме аякс? Может быть я уже подобное и задавал, но прошу еще раз тогда мне ответить. И еще, кому не трудно и кто хорошо знает аякс могу ли я с вами связаться. Если да тогда вот мой скайп palosh65.

P.S. Спасибо тем, кто выслушал.

Comment: а теперь по-русски.

Тебе нужно при нажатии ссылки сделать Ajax запрос или чтобы что-то прошлось по сайту и покликало на ссылки?

Answer (score 1):

[Русская документация по Jquery (Ajax)](http://jquery-docs.ru/Ajax/)

Сначала прочти это, а потом, если что не поймешь - спрашивай, так куда лучше и полезней.

Comment: честно говоря я не разбираюсь в аяксе поэтому даже документация не очень мне понятна